# Can this be achieved with 1 replace statement and 1 regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to remove all all occurrences of '-' and include '-' after 5 digit.

```js
console.log("12-34--5-444-4444".replace(/-/g, '').replace(/(\d{5})/, "$1-"));
```

Comment: I suspect the answer is "yes, that can be done", but I worry that the resulting regex would be significantly more difficult for a human to parse and understand while the original code provided is pretty straightforward and in all likelihood performs well enough.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: You can do multiple replacements in a single regexp by using a function as the replacement, but it won't be able to operate on the result of earlier replacements.

Comment: It could be done like this,  but it's pretty ugly imo and you're better off using a normal loop instead of replace: https://jsfiddle.net/k2yn38ur/, I think what you have is fine

Comment: Nick Parsons  This doesn't work if there is no '-'.

Answer (score 1):

It's *possible*, but I wouldn't recommend it, since the logic, while concise, isn't terribly clear at a glance at the code. You can use JavaScript's variable-length lookbehind to check that the match of a `-` is not preceded by exactly 5 digits before the beginning of the string:

```js
console.log("12-34--5-444-4444".replace(/(?<!^(?:\d-*){5})-/g, ''));
```

Thus `-`s which are preceded by 1 to 4 digits, or preceded by 6 or more digits, will be matched by the pattern and removed.

Comment: This only works if there's already a `-` after the 5th digit.